# Javascript- Only first function loads

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having trouble trying to make my functions work properly.

```js
function myFunction() {

  // This part appends a number before a label with the class "enum"

  var enumField = document.getElementsByClassName('enum');
  for (var z = 0; z <= enumField.length; z++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = z + 1 + '.- ';
    enumField[z].parentNode.insertBefore(span, enumField[z]);
  }

  //This other part changes the background color of an element with the class "fieldsetColor"

  var fieldsetStyle = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldsetColor');
  for (var i = 0; i <= fieldsetStyle.length; i++) {
      fieldsetStyle[i].style.backgroundColor = 'palegoldenrod';
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction();">
  <div>Student</div>
  <form id="myForm">
    <fieldset class="fieldsetColor">
      <legend>Personal Data </legend>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Placeholder"><br>
      <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
      <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text">
      <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
      <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text"> 
      <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
      <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

The main problem is that only the first part of the function works (the one that enumerates), and the second part does not work.

If I swap the position of the first part and the second one, the same happens (only the background color is changed).

What could be the problem? Is my syntax wrong? Is something wrong with the `<body onload="myFunction()">`?

I'm really afraid that this could be silly question... I'm trying to learn by myself but sometimes I get lost and can't seem to formulate the right question...

Thanks in advance! ☺

Comment: There's an error at the end of the `for` loop, so it does not continue on to what's below. Check your browser console. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined` (Always open your console before wondering why things aren't working as they should)

Comment: i.e. you're using `<=` instead of `<` in the for loops

Comment: Thanks to all of you! :D @CertainPerformance I'm gonna look more often at my console! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually just looping once more than you need to. Since arrays are zero indexed, you don't want `z <= enumField.length` but rather `z < enumField.length`. Since this error was halting the function, nothing continued.

```js
function myFunction() {

    // This part appends a number before a label with the class "enum"

    var enumField = document.getElementsByClassName('enum');
    for (var z = 0; z < enumField.length; z++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = z + 1 + '.- ';
        console.log(enumField[z]);
        enumField[z].parentNode.insertBefore(span, enumField[z]);

    }

    //This other part changes the background color of an element with the class "fieldsetColor"

    var fieldsetStyle = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldsetColor');
    for (var i = 0; i <= fieldsetStyle.length; i++) {
        fieldsetStyle[i].style.backgroundColor = 'palegoldenrod';

    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction();">
<div>Student</div>
<form id="myForm">
    <fieldset class="fieldsetColor">

        <legend>Personal Data </legend>

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Placeholder"><br>

        <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
        <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text">
        <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
        <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text"> 
        <label class="reqInput enum"  for="nombreInput">Nombre: </label>
        <input id="nombreInput" name="nombre" type="text">

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Well... Yep, that was the problem... Thank you very much! I didn't realize that a single "<="  could be the problem... 

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by your for loop condition. You probably get an Array Index Out of Bounds exception.

you use

```
z <= enumField.length
```

but it should be

```
z < enumField.length
```